# How do you keep the left position relative to screen size? Titanium

Tags: ios, iphone, titanium-mobile

I am having trouble dealing with different screen sizes. I initially coded my app for iphone 4, now with the higher models and bigger screens , everything is out of position.

Left: '100dp'

will not visually sit in the same place as on the iphone 6 because the screen is wider.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You could use percentages for the width of the elements. That would make them scalable.

Comment: Sure, but if I wanted to be specific about the left position. I can't.

Comment: By _not visually sit in the same place_ do you mean the distance from the left edge to the view is different?

Comment: yeah basically that.

Answer (score 0):

Designing the UI using percentages is the best practice and it has worked for me till now but if you are adamant on using fixed values then the way around is to get the device width and height  using Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth,
Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight,
and then determining where you want to put those UI elements, but this is a lengthy process and you might end up pissed off.

Comment: I have found when doing percentages , on different screen resolutions the percentage doesnt always place the element in the correct position. The other problem with it, you cannot be specific enough. Say I wanted to do left=3.5dp , whats the % equivilent